How to configure JMeter in AWS Distributed Load Testing (DLT) to access Avro .bin files for the load?
I'm setting up a Distributed Load Test (DLT) in AWS using JMeter. My test configuration requires loading data from an Avro .bin file. Locally, I simply specify the local file's path in JMeter, and it works as expected. However, I am struggling to figure out how to handle this in the AWS DLT environment.
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/distributed-load-testing-on-aws/
Here are my specific concerns:

Where should I upload the .bin file so that all worker instances in
the DLT can access it? In a local setup, I just use a direct path.
But in AWS, the workers are spun up dynamically, so I can't rely on a
specific file path.
How can I configure JMeter to ensure the test
grabs this file during execution in the DLT setup?

I’ve considered the following approaches but need guidance:

Uploading the file to S3 and downloading it dynamically at runtime.
Preloading the file on worker instances via custom AMIs or startup
scripts.
Creating a new Task definition in ECS and try to use the entrypoint script to try to copy from a s3 the file to the instance

All of them seems to be kind of complicated. And I am not sure it could work.
If you’ve faced a similar situation or have a best-practice recommendation for handling external resource files like this in AWS DLT, I’d appreciate your help!
Update
I read in another post that we can attach a file packaged in a ZIP file together with the JMeter config. I tried but still it is not able to run the test.


<elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
            <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
              <elementProp name="LscTestEvent.bin" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
                <stringProp name="File.mimetype">application/octet-stream</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.path">LscTestEvent.bin</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.paramname"></stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>



